# How to understand what is happening in this freshman X-ray scattering diagram?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, scattering, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

In this Yale chemistry course I am taking on YouTube, I am stuck on something [at 21:36 in the lecture](https://youtu.be/cm9W10Kg8q4?list=PL3F629F73640F831D&t=1305). I am trying to understand the diagram [Professor McBride](https://chem.yale.edu/people/j-michael-mcbride) is using to explain how X-Rays scatter when they hit electrons (from what I understand). Unfortunately he glossses over details about this diagram.

Perhaps someone here has seen it before and has a better understanding of it.

Are the 3 rows of electons representative of the electrons in a crystal?
Is the X-Ray the vertical line?
When he "changes the angle" by sliding the right bar up and down, what exactly does that represent?
How do we know the electrons' paths will line up so perfectly? Won't their paths be completely chaotic and not aligned?

I would really appreciate a good explanation of what this represents.

[image: XRay Scattering Angle]

[image: Light Scattering Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

X-rays scatter in all directions. He is considering one direction at a time, and looking for the condition that creates constructive interference in that direction.

You will get constructive interference if crests line of for x-rays scattered from many atoms. It depends on the spacing between atoms, the X-ray wavelength, and the direction.

He is showing that the initial direction does not result in constructive interference.

He tilts the point of view to look X-rays scattered in another direction. The crests do line up. There will be constructive interference in that direction.

Comment: Thanks! So in the example, what represents the direction from and to where the x-rays are travelling?

Comment: X-rays are traveling from left to right, as shown by the horizontal blue arrows. The x-rays are a plane wave. When the X-ray hit the atoms, they scatter in all directions. In this case they scatter from a vertical row of atoms. You can see that the phase at the atoms is all the same. This is what you would expect from a plane wave from the left.

Comment: In the diagram then, the x-rays are represented by the straight horizontal LINES and NOT the horizontal WAVES? Did I get that right?

Comment: The scattered waves are shown as waves so you can see their phase. Their direction is shown at green arrows. The incoming waves are not shown, but their direction is shown by the blue arrows.